# Name of code style

Tags: php, coding-style

When I develop my PHP code I always write it a certain way, I use the following to define my variables:

```
$sString
$aArray
$bBoolean
$oObject
$mMixed
$iInteger
$a_sString/aArray/bBoolean ect (for function argument)
```

Hence s, a, b, o, m, i ect.  I know there is a name to call this type of writing, but I have totally forgotten it.

My question: What is this called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's similar to ["Hungarian"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260976%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), but it's actually [PAHN](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/Alternative_Hungarian_Notation).

Answer (score 3):

It's called [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

**Note:** There are many different "flavors" of Hungarian. "Hungarian" by itself describes the practice of prefixing variable names with a few characters that provide additional information about the contents of the variable. *What* kind of information is what defines the actual flavor in use.

Comment: Thank you. I went for PAHN since this is PHP code, but it sure was interesting reading for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Hungarian notation** is an identifier naming convention in computer programming, in which the name of a variable or function indicates its type or intended use.

Answer (score 0):

this is some kind of [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), but some kind (seems to be very close to [pahn](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/Alternative_Hungarian_Notation)) of the missunderstood and useless one*. take a look at [joels great article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) about hungarian notation and how to use it the correct way.

*just using a prefix to see what *type* a variable should be isn't very useful - it you be way better to prefix them with something that defines what *kind* of variable this is. an example:

lets assume you have some variables containing different currencys (euros and dollars, in cents for your case as you havnt given a prefix fpr floats, so i'll use integers) and a function to ververt one to another. in your case:

```
$iPriceAmerica = 500;

// would be the right way
$iPriceEurope = iEuroFromDollar($iPriceAmerica);

// looks right and is possible as both are integers
// but is wrong (correct executable code, but doesn't give the expected result)
$iPriceEurope = $iPriceAmerica;
```

with correct hungarian notation, using `dol_` for dollars and `eur_` for euros:

```
$dol_PriceAmerica = 500;

// would be the right way
$eur_PriceEurope = eur_from_dol($dol_PriceAmerica);

// looks wrong - eur isn't dol, there muste be some kind of conversion
$eur_PriceEurope = $dol_PriceAmerica;
```